# Huyegns Principle and data transmission

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Huygens's principle (The Gist) states that for every object on which light is incident every point on that object acts a light source till light is being incident on it.

So is it possible than WiFi which is based on Radio waves also be affected by Huygens' principle like every particle in the wall adjacent to my Router becomes a source rather than an obstacle

Comment: Of course, that's exactly why wireless routers were impractical until we could integrate the necessary electronics for modulation methods (OFDM) that are insensitive to such reflections. More importantly, though, all such reflections are still perfectly linear functions between transmitter and receiver and they allow for such things as antenna-diversity, which will allow us to grow the useful transmission rates of these devices by another one or two orders of magnitude.

Comment: Note also that Huygens' principle applies to *any* surface *anywhere*,  not just surfaces of real objects.  Mathematically defined surfaces in empty space are also subject to the principle.  So not only is every wall a radiator, but every imaginable surface in space is a radiator.  The relationship between Huygens' principle and *reflections* is not as direct as you make it sound.